# Why is the schema generated by Fluent NHibernate read-only?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, iesi-collections

I have the following code:

```
var schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
schemaExport.Drop(false, true);
schemaExport.Create(false, true);

Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
  .MsSql2008
  .ConnectionString(connString))
  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ProductMap>())
  .ExposeConfiguration(CreateSchema)
  .BuildConfiguration();
```

The above code successfully creates the two tables defined elsewhere, but when I do "Edit top 200 rows" in SSMS, I find that the cells are read-only.

There is no obvious mention of any read-only directive in the code files, mappings, or anywhere else.

Why is the schema generated as read-only?

I am using VS 2010, .NET 4 Client FW, FluentNHibernate 2.0.3.0, NHibernate 4.0.0.4000, Iesi.Collections 4.0.0.4000, on Windows 7 Ultimate x86.

The above code is from this book: [NHibernate 3 Beginner's Guide [2011]](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/nhibernate-3-beginners-guide)

Comment: I don't think this is related to NH or the fluent mappings. It sounds more like a SQL Server/SMSS issue. Have you got enough privilege to alter the data?

Comment: Well done. I've posted my comment as an answer. You can accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to NH or the fluent mappings. It sounds more like a SQL Server/SMSS issue. Have you got enough privilege to alter the data?

Comment: Thank you, your answer clued me to the actual problem. I was trying to edit an identity column!